# Three-in-one-regex

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I have a very specific regex request. I need to match strings

- containing "m_",
- *not* containing "phys_" (always some characters after "m_"),
- *not* ending in "Shape".

When only using the first and last criteria this regex seems to work fine:

```
^.*m_.*(?<!Shape)$
```

But when I added the middle criteria I was lost.

Comment: What language is the regex implemented in? Why are you trying to perform three tasks in one regular expression when you could be using 3 reasonably simple regular expressions?

Comment: @zzzzBov: Python. I use the same regex functionality for various other things as well in my homebrew configuration system. (It's done the job wonderfully up until this point, so not inclined to replace it any time soon.)

Comment: Let me save this question. 
I think the programming language is not so important when we talk about regex (in ideal case:) ), and why not solve a problem with one regexp? More elegant than using '3 reasonably simple regular expressions'. Yes we should thinking more, but why not :)

Comment: @Kovge: Regex is good when the pattern is not fixed. But all 3 conditions involves "containing" or "ends with" static text, which can be done with normal string processing functions.

Comment: If egrep is also an option, you could go with this: `cat $filename | egrep -v '(phys_|Shape$)' | grep 'm_'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex you want is

```
^(?=.*m_)(?!.*phys_)(?!.*Shape$).*$
```

It will capture the entire string, and each condition is in it's own lookahead. You can test it and see a visualization of what's happening on [www.debuggex.com](http://www.debuggex.com/?re=%5E%28?=.%2am_%29%28?!.%2aphys_%29%28?!.%2aShape%24%29.%2a%24&flags=&str=m_asdShapefphys).

Comment: With all due respect, how is this different from my answer?

Comment: The question asked to match the string if the conditions are true. Your answer only matches the empty string. Your regex also deals with m_ in the phys_ condition, which is redundant.

Comment: @thg435: It's shorter and more to the point, although you were faster! :)

Comment: @JonasByström: yes, it looks like I misinterpreted your requirements ("always some characters after etc"). Next time, please try to be more specific! And no, the `.*$` part doesn't make any sense, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

```
import re

r = re.compile(r'^(?=.*m_)(?!.*m_.+phys_)(?!.+Shape$)')
print r.match("aaa")
print r.match("aaa m_ xx")
print r.match("aaa m_ xx Shape")
print r.match("aaa m_ xx phys_ foo")
```

Basically, the principle is:

```
  ^
  (?= .* should be there)
  (?! .* should not be there)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with normal string methods in Python (I add brackets for clarity):

```
("m_" in input) and ("phys_" not in input) and (not input.endswith("Shape"))
```

I interpret *(always some characters after "m_")* as a hint that "phys_" never appears in front of "m_", rather than allowing the case where "phys_" comes in front of "m_" to pass.

Comment: I want a regex string, not a python statement, as it's part of a configuration file.

Comment: @JonasByström: Include that fact in your question next time. I don't think regex is a good solution in this case, but if the tool doesn't allow any other option, then it makes your request for regex a valid one.